# extract text from select button using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Hi guys I am trying using Javascript to extract the name

```
<div class="dropdown-container">
      <form>
         <select id="pick-chart" class="form-control pick-chart">
             <option value="0">Compare with</option>
             {% for i in team_list_pop %}
             <option value="{{i.id}}">{{i.first_name}} {{i.last_name}}</option>
             {% endfor %}
         </select>
      </form>
 </div>
```

In my JS I tried :

```
$(".pick-chart").change(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var val = $(this).val();
        var name2 = $("option value=" +'"'+val+'"').text();
}
```

and I got the error :`Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognised expression: option value="52"`

How could I extract {i.first_name}} ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JQuery text is wrong, try this:

```
const name2 = $(`option[value='${val}']`).text();
```

Then to get just the first name (assuming the first name contains no spaces):

```
const firstName = name2.split(' ')[0]
```

Comment: thx men ;)
For some reason when I console.log(name2) I get :
Julien DoréJulien DoréJulien DoréJulien Doré instead of Julien Doré, is there a way to extract only Julien the first name ?

Comment: It sounds to me like you have multiple options for that id, in that instance using `$(\`option[value='${val}']\`).first().text()` will get the first full name, with `.split(' ')[0]` getting the first name.

Answer (score 1):

You have incorrectly written the code for `var name2 = $("option value=" +'"'+val+'"').text();` , replace that with `var name2 = $('option[value='+val+']').text();` and it will work. You also have a `missing )` error for the `change` function so add a closing parenthesis there. For the working snippet I have removed the dynamic `option` elements:

```js
$(".pick-chart").change(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var val = $(this).val();
    var name2 = $('option[value='+val+']').text();
    var fName = name2.split(' ')[0];
    console.log('first name is ', fName);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown-container">
      <form>
         <select id="pick-chart" class="form-control pick-chart">
             <option value="0">Compare with</option>
             <option value="someVal">John Cena</option>
         </select>
      </form>
 </div>
```